# Swagger-UI displaying subtypes in response model

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to display all subtypes
that response can contain
using JSON like this

https://gist.github.com/szegi/19db500183bb3d3d20fd27a913f59505

i declared response like this

```
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "successful operation",
                    "schema": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/Dog"
                            },
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/Cat"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
```

but i get only response with all properties of both definitions using swagger ui,

but trying the same in https://editor2.swagger.io/#!/ i get better result

[image]

is there any way to display it like this in swagger-ui or maybe i miss something in my configuration?

im using newest Swagger UI - version 3x

and i tried to use online demo
http://petstore.swagger.io/ and import this file

Comment: Which [version of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) do you use? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Helen it looks like live demo http://petstore.swagger.io/ so its newest i downloaded it today